# Telegram bot - importing contacts and request for number

Tags: contacts, telegram

We have a company that has to get in touch with its user over Telegram, we've been thinking a lot and this is what came to my mind, I just want to know is it really possible to do such thing or not.

So basically we made an account to be our customer care service where people can tell us what their problem is and stuff. We also gathered all of our users Phone numbers + first and last name into a xlsx file during their first ever purchase.

Now this has to be done:
Is it possible to import all the phone numbers + names into a bot, and then whenever we receive a message from a customer on our customer care account, we forward their message to the bot, and it gives us their phone number.

This is technically possible for the account itself (not bot) but as Telegram has a limitation for number of contacts (I think it's 10k per acc), we can't do it. (We have over 50k users)

Is that clear or more explanation is needed.

P.S: My question was if it's possible to create a bot to be able to receive a message from a customer and return their number. (We already have their number so it's just like a quick search)

Additional info: If telegram did not have such limitation for number of contacts, we could simply add 50k contacts with a vcf file (on a phone) and see their number when they message us but since there is a limitation, we just want the bot to do this job for us but it has to able to give us their number too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will require a lot of work to setup, but it could be done.

Telegram gives every user a userid, but it won't tell you the phone number given that user id. So you have to get the userid by asking Telegram "what userid has phone number xyz" for every user and storing that information.

While it is possible to use the bot api and send a contact with each number to get the user_id of that user, the bot api is rate limited, and 50k users will either trigger that rate limit or will require some time.

Comment: Thank you very much, so as I understood it's gonna be hard. Is there anyway that this process could be done automatically? No matter how longs it takes (hopefully not more than a couple of days) Like I give the bot a vcf/xlsx file and it finds each number userid and save it in its database and then whenever I ask for someone userid, it give me the number. Is it as hard as the previous idea? (And I suppose their userid changes whenever they delete their account and make a new one with same number or just change their number via telegram itself, right?)

Comment: Or just let me make it as short as possible, Is there anyway I can have access to 50k numbers on Telegram, normally it would require 5 different numbers (10k on each one) but I would like to have them all in 1 account (No matter if it's on 1 number or 1 bot)

Comment: Your first solution can work (sending every number as contact, extract the user_id), but you will have problems with changing userids (account deletion, number change, later joining telegram). Automation is possible, basically just `curl` and json parsing and waiting a bit to avoid to flood the telegram servers.